# are there java/jvm agnostic framework for json-document NoSQL

Tags: java, json, nosql

Given: There are multiple document-storage type NoSQL systems such as couchdb/base, mongodb, and aws-dynamodb (that can be both document and key-value). cross-check research:  Document-storage based NoSQL systems can be found here: http://nosql-database.org/

When: Different nosql types (key-value, document store, etc) provide different benefits depending on what you are trying to implement.  In the case of this question, document-storage of JSON content is desired, and evaluating a way to implement a good document-storage solution and test against different nosql databases is desired.

Question: Are there JVM-based frameworks (java, scala, groovy, whatever) that would provide an agnostic overlay similar to JPA and other ORM's that would allow implement-once code and test run against different nosql databases without rewirting the code (only change the configuration)?

Note: http://hibernate.org/ogm/ is one such example, but only lists one document-store based nosql database supported.

Comment: wow, what is wrong with this question versus just minusing it out?

Comment: Are you asking if something like this exists? http://hibernate.org/ogm/

Comment: yeah, that's a good one, although it only has one document-based nosql (mongodb) supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) currently has modules for Redis, MongoDB, Couchbase, DynamoDB and several other NoSQL databases.

The [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) project currently supports MongoDB and Neo4j.

It looks like there is also JPA support for [CouchBase](http://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-jpa-level-2-cache-0), [MongoDB](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/NoSQL) and [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview).

Comment: neat, what do you mean by JPA support for those databases....is it something new in the spec or an ORM implementation added support for them?

Comment: Well you can read about that in the links I posted. JPA is a standard. JPA supports plugins, and there are also completely different implementations of JPA which support different databases including some NoSQL databases.

Comment: 57k reputation and you answer an off topic library request?

Comment: @Raedwald he's not specifically asking for a recommendation, so it seems like a gray area to me. Discussions about this sort of thing on Meta usually come down to this: "Would the answer be helpful to other users in the future?" I felt like a list of these libraries would be of some use to others in the future, so I answered the question instead of flagging it. If there was an explicit flag for "Question shows no research attempt" then I would have flagged it with that instead of answering it.

Comment: I was also trying to avoid the word 'recommendation' as it would immediately get removed and shift to 'software recommendations' Q&A that **do not** have the experts available to address the question, as it is a developer framework question.

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/ogm/) seems to have what you are looking for.